# Implement route functionality with google place API for android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am going to implement functionality to input current location (with out using GPS) for particular path. Following are the two options.

1. Since I know the path I can either predefined all the inter mediate location from start to end. So user can select valid location for the particular path. Since it is predefined. But since this is hard coded it is bit overhead to maintain.
2. Use google place API. But there I can not restrict user to input specific locations between start and end. User can select invalid location which is not relevant.

What is the better approach I have to follow by overcoming the limitations?

Comment: I think there is a 2nd option is much better you can't restrict the user you can show the user through error message or supporting message like doesn't support in the specific area.

Comment: @TanveerMunir Is it possible to check particular location is not between the start and end. And it should be possible to select only major places between start and end.

Comment: there is no specific method or anything which you can check but you check by manually stored a JSON file which has allowed or disallowed locations when you select the location you can check from this and pass on.